# Intro to Probability

Tags: probability

A person randomly places 9 rooks on a 9 by 9 grid (the 8 by 8 case corresponds to a chess board). What is the probability that none of the rooks can capture any of the other rooks?

I have a good start on the problem, but I think that I am possibly missing a step or something. Any hits would be apprciated. I know that each time you place a rook, you lose spaces that you can place the next rook. It goes 9^2 spaces to 8^2 spaces to 7^2 spaces...down to 1 space at the end. Thats for the chances to satisfy the problem. For total options it goes 81 spaces to 80 spaces down to 72 when you place the last rook. So my answer is (81*64*49*36*25*16*9*4*1)/(81*80*79*78*77*76*75*74*73*72) Am I missing anything here?Thank you

Comment: Notational convenience: Your denominator is $81^{\underline{10}}$, $81$ to the power of $10$ falling.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, placing 9 rooks on a 9x9 chessboard so that they don't attack each other is equivalent to asking how many permutations there are of the numbers $1,2,\cdots,9$. This is because each allowed rook configuration corresponds to a $9\times 9$ permutation matrix $M$, with $M_{ij}=1$ if there's a rook at $(i,j)$ and 0 otherwise: there cannot be two 1's on the same row or column. So the answer is immediately $9!/\binom{81}{9}$.

Comment: I have withdrawn my downvote after your edit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: your approach is okay and your answer is *almost* okay. There is a factor $72$ in your denominator that must be left out and that's all. As you will understand it concerns $9$ factors (and not $10$). An alternative way:

For selecting $9$ spots in such a way that the rooks placed on them cannot capture other rooks there are $9!$ possibilities. For selecting $9$ spots of $81$ without any condition there are $\binom{81}{9}$ ways. This gives a probability of $$9!\times\binom{81}{9}^{-1}$$ to place the rooks at random in such a way that they cannot capture other rooks.

Working this out you come to $$\frac{9^2\times8^2\times\cdots\times1^2}{81\times80\times\cdots\times 73}$$

matching your answer (if factor $72$ has been taken away there).

Answer (score -1):

Don't have enough points for a comment, but you seem to be contradicting yourself when you first say that for the first rook you have 9^2 , for the second you have 8^2 and then for the total options you cite 81, 80, etc.

Comment: Thanks, my 'delete' is disabled, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Brilliant! Punishing me because I am unable to delete my question.

Comment: If I understand you well then you want to delete this question, but somehow you are not able to do so. If that's so then let me know. I could flag your question and request moderators to delete it. Are you unable to flag it yourself? I don't think someone is trying to punish you.